# I have timestamp column in a table, i want to find difference each consecutive rows in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have data like this:

```
student_id                   date
        34                05-03-2019
        34                15-04-2019
        78                06-12-2018
```

I want something like this

```
  student_id               date         Time_difference
     34                05-03-2019          45
     34                15-04-2019          5
     78                20-04-2018
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `LEAD` can be used here with `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT
    student_id,
    date,
    DATEDIFF(LEAD(date) OVER (ORDER BY date), date) AS Time_difference
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY date;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, we can use a correlated subquery in place of `LEAD`:

```
SELECT
    student_id,
    date,
    DATEDIFF(
        (SELECT t2.date FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.date > t1.date
         ORDER BY t2.date LIMIT 1),
        date) AS Time_difference
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: I want something like this:
             date            Time_difference 
        05-03-2019             40
        15-04-2019             5
        20-04-2018             1
        21-04-2018

Comment: I have answered the question you actually did ask.

Answer (score 0):

I want something like this:
          date            Time_difference 
        05-03-2019             40
        15-04-2019             5
        20-04-2018             1
        21-04-2018